# How to add category name in the url of product only in category page

Tags: magento2

I need to change the product url as below,

https://shop.com/productname+sku.html.

And also add category name like this https://shop.com/categoryname+productname+sku.html in the category list page only.

How can i achieve this.

Comment: in category page there are lost of product so you have to show all product name and sku in category url ?

Comment: Please explain more in detail.

Comment: @Msquare No i didn't mean that. If l click product in tha page of category that time that product URL will be "https://shop.com/categoryname+productname+sku.html". If i click product using cross-sell section or in the cart page that time product url will be "https://shop.com/productname+sku.html" .

Answer (score 0):

This can be managed in the Admin Config:

Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization -> "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" set to "Yes"

[image]